# load texture with "textureWithContentsOfFile" on Retina Displays not working

Tags: ios, textures, retina-display, glkit

I have strange problem with GLKit on IOS development.

Here is my texture loader method:

```
(id)initWithFile:(NSString *)fileName effect:(GLKBaseEffect *)effect {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    self.effect = effect;
    NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                                       GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft,
                              nil];
    NSError * error;
    NSString *path0 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil];
    NSLog(@"Path for Image: %@",path0);
    self.texture0Info = [GLKTextureLoader    textureWithContentsOfFile:path0 options:options error:&error];
    if (self.texture0Info == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error loading file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return nil;
    }
    TexturedQuad newQuad;
    newQuad.bl.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    newQuad.br.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(self.texture0Info.width/2, 0);
    newQuad.tl.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(0, self.texture0Info.height/2);
    newQuad.tr.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(self.texture0Info.width/2, self.texture0Info.height/2);

    newQuad.bl.texture0Vertex = CGPointMake(0,1);
    newQuad.br.texture0Vertex = CGPointMake(1,1);
    newQuad.tl.texture0Vertex = CGPointMake(0,0);
    newQuad.tr.texture0Vertex = CGPointMake(1,0);

    self.quad = newQuad;
    self.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.texture0Info.width, self.texture0Info.height);

}

return self;
}
```

and I call this method from my GLKViewController

```
-(void)addBubbleImage{

SpriteThings * bubbleImage = [[ SpriteThings alloc]initWithFile:@"Rectangler.png" effect:self.effect];
bubbleImage.position=GLKVector2Make(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y);
[self.screenThings addObject:bubbleImage];

}
```

the weird thing is that it is working on non-retina display and image loaded correctly. But on retina display doesn't appear anything both of on device and simulator. I have Rectangler.png and Rectangler@2x.png files on my project in same directory. but still stuck. What do you think?

Comment: Problem is getting weird. It works on iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, iPad 2, iPad Retina. And doesn't works on iPhone 5s, iPhone6, iPhone 6 Plus and iPad Air. İOS 7.1 and 8.1 same result.

Comment: I think I found solition. it is related 64 bit architecture. I changed everything related CGPoint to GLKVector2 and problem solved.